# Vue.js nextTick inside computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have "context menu" component. Computed properties `top` and `left` define menu position using `$event` property. But when I trying to open context menu, menu element is not rendered yet and `top` cannot be calculated without menu's `offsetHeight`, so I figured out to use some "`nextTick` hack" inside computed property:

```
top() {
  if (!this.menuIsRendered) { // by default, menuIsRendered is false 
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.menuIsRendered = true
    })

    return 0
  }

  ... // menu element is rendered, calculate top value
},
```

Is this ok? I think there must be a better way to do this.

Also, full component code:

```
<template>
  <div ref="menu" :style="{top: `${top}px`, left: `${left}px`}"
    v-click-outside="close" @contextmenu.prevent v-if="show">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'show',
    'event'
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      menuIsRendered: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    top() {
      if (!this.menuIsRendered) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.menuIsRendered = true
        })

        return 0
      }

      let top = this.event.y
      let largestHeight = window.innerHeight - this.$refs.menu.offsetHeight - 25

      return top > largestHeight ? largestHeight : top + 1
    },
    left() {
      if (!this.menuIsRendered) {
        return 0
      }

      let left = this.event.x
      let largestWidth = window.innerWidth - this.$refs.menu.offsetWidth - 25

      return left > largestWidth ? largestWidth : left + 1
    },
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.$emit('close')
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Component usage:

```
<context-menu @close="close" :event="event" :show="show">
  <div @click="doAction">Action</div>
  <div @click="doAnotherAction">Another action</div>
</context-menu>
```

Answer (score -3):

Normally, computed properties must be synchronous. If you want this properties asynchronous, you should use this plugin : https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed

> With this plugin, you can have computed properties in Vue that are computed asynchronously. Without using this plugin, you can't do this.

Now you can set asynchrone computeds with the `asyncComputed` property :

```
asyncComputed: {
  username () {
    return Vue.http.get('/get-username-by-id/' + this.userId)
      .then(response => response.data.username)
  }
}
```

Comment: What "you can't do this" mean? My component is working fine. Also, `nextTick` not returns a promise, so, can I actually use this plugin?

Comment: Oh, actually, `nextTick` returns a Promise  "New in 2.1.0: returns a Promise if no callback is provided and Promise is supported in the execution environment."

Comment: I just copy the introduction of the plugin. In this case it responds to your problem ;)

Comment: But I'm just not sure that changing default behavior of computed properties is better than adding a flag :)

Comment: In this case, you should use a method, not a computed property, hat will update a data field

Comment: You mean I should `watch` `$event` and call `setPosition`, which changes `top` and `left`?

Comment: But why change the `menuIsRendered` on the call of top/left ? In this case the `menuIsRendered` is true directly at the first call. I don't understand why you want exactly. 
Normally, an option like that is changed at an `open` event on your context Menu. You shoud calculate top and left at this moment

Comment: Default `menuIsRendered` is `false`. It changes to `true` after `nextTick`, when menu is rendered. Also, what do you mean by `open` event? That I should use "Bus" for this situation? (like `Bus.$on('open', this.$nextTick(this.setPosition()))`)